# How can I enable Suitescript IntelliSense on vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, netsuite, suitescript, code-completion

I want IntelliSense for suitescript on vs code, I tried to put the netsuite2.0 API (the one downloadable from file cabinet) folder with the definitions made a jsconfig.json with only a {} in my workspace like some tutorials says but it doesn't work.
I also tried the extension GVO snippets, in the details it says that have context support for a serie of functions but it seems that it does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super late, you probably just need to add some JSDoc to your code. I have this in mine and it works (mostly) fine:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(['N/https', 'N/record', 'N/runtime'], 
/**
 * 
 * @param {https} https 
 * @param {record} record 
 * @param {runtime} runtime 
 */
function (https, record, runtime) {
...
```

That being said, there appears to be some issue still with some of the APIs. Intellisense doesn't work for `record.Type` for example. I assume it's an issue in NetSuite's API.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for a solution to the 2.0 API issue, please check out [SuiteSnippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ericbirdsall.SuiteSnippets) in VS Codes Extension marketplace. It’s an extension I built to solve to bring an intellisense feel VS Code for SuiteScript 2.0.

Would really appreciate any feedback!

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ericbirdsall.SuiteSnippets

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. By my read, you're doing alright since you've disclosed your association and this seems relevant to addressing the original question. Still, I'd be sure to read [How not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) to make sure you don't run afoul of Stack Overflow's self-promotion rules.